Adverbs with Avec
I'm trying to learn if there are any rules for words that need avec when they become an adverb (avec facilité). Normally you'd add -ment for an adverb, lentement/vraiment. I have been wondering if it has some background to it. Like if it came from Latin or why they would use avec? It would look like a weird choose to me. So if someone is able to provide some answers to this. It would be appreciated!
Regards,
Dutch Student (:

Facile doesn't need avec as you can use facilement and lentement can be avec lenteur.

But you can't exchange every word like that can you? and why so that there are 2 ways. For that I know only -ment is learned. Or are there some differences in meaning? And the avec form isn't used a lot isn't it?

Avec facilité is not exactly an adverb but an adverbial phrase. You can surely find an equivalent one to any adverb in -ment.

So that means that there isn't really a difference between the 2 forms?

There might be multiple adverbial phrases matching a single adverb, and the adverbial phrases aren't necessarily built the same way. The difference is similar to the one between the adveb 'easily' and the adverbial phrases 'with ease/with facility/without effort/...'

@jlliagre "an equivalent one to any adverb in -ment" as in:  intelligemment --> avec intelligence; bruyamment --> avec bruyance. Sorry, couldn't resist.

@FrançoisJurain Yes, bruyance is nice if not a little outdated ;-) That's why I wrote 'not necessarily built the same way'. Bruyamment → avec bruit (rare)/avec fracas/...

@jlliagre: In English, without effort has the adverb effortlessly; without shame, the adverb shamelessly; wihtout noise, the adverb noiselessly. But I can't think of a French suffix equivalent to –lessly.

@PeterShor Right, we use no suffix here (both -less and -ly are Germanic) but kind of a detached prefix : sans effort, sans honte, sans bruit. The suffix -ly correspond to the French -ment but is unused in negative forms (no ---"sans bruyamment"---), we would use silencieusement instead.

The "avec" way should not be unknown coming from English (I know nothing about Dutch). "With (great) surprise", "with haste", "with caution" are commonly used.
As for the origin, it seems that this "manner" meaning for "avec" doesn't stem from Latin usage indeed.
It's just how French (and English!) evolved, starting at most from 15th century.
There is little difference with the -ment fashion, apart from a wider application range while using "avec" (same source).
In daily French language, this difference is barely noticeable most of the times though (but still present, partly because you can quantify the circumstance; e.g. "avec grande honte" vs. "honteusement", while choices are fewer (typically très/very) with -ment/-ly).
